# Where can I find recent rainforest (change) land cover data?

Tags: land-cover

I want to try to get a handle on what's becoming of the world's rainforests right now but not seeming to find recent (i.e. around 2010) data.

The stuff here:

http://www.glcf.umd.edu/data/

as far as I can tell goes up to about 2006, but no further.

I am principally interested in the Amazon and Borneo rainforests.

Answer (score 2):

I did succeed in finding this:

http://www.vgt.vito.be/

...but I have no idea how to use the data therein. Examining the pixels of a given HDF gives me a bunch of integers without clearly defined semantics.

Look at this:

http://glcf.umiacs.umd.edu/data/treecover/

While it's from 2000, I can at least tell what the numbers mean; see heading "Code Values".

I also don't know the technical name of the "plate carrée" projection it's supposed to be in, so that I can project it properly in QGIS or GRASS.

Comment: You may want to create a new question (referencing old question) about how to use this data type.

Comment: Alright, will do.