# How do I use the SPOT land cover data?

Tags: land-cover

This is a follow-up to my previous question:

[Where can I find recent rainforest (change) land cover data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44899/where-can-i-find-recent-rainforest-change-land-cover-data)

I have succeeded in finding data that more or less meet my needs but I cannot interpret them:

http://www.vgt.vito.be/

Examining the NDVI layer in QGIS, I see that the pixels are integer-valued, but their meaning is not clear. You will notice that on the (older) data on the GLCF site define what these sorts of numbers *mean*. Unless I'm missing something, I can't find those instructions to go with the SPOT data.